# Odd behavior in salesforce flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am working on a rather extensive flow. It doesn't pertain to my question to talk about what it does. Quite simply, I am baffled at the way the 'is null' operator is working in a decision element. At the very start of my flow, I am checking if two of the triggering record's fields are null. If they are, I want the record to take a defined path. Otherwise, the record should take the default path. Here is a snap shot of how I have this set up:
[image]

However, when I go to run the flow debugger, I get some odd behavior. Since the record I am running the flow with the debugger does not haver either the 'individual email' or 'individual linked in url' fields set, I would expect the debugger to take my 'No unique person identifiers' path. However, it is taking my default path. Here is a picture of the debugger message and flow path (please keep in mind that BOTH the relevant field are not set, so should be null):

[image]

[image]

Since both of the relevant fields are not set yet, I would expect the record to take my defined path, rather than the default outcome. Why is this happening? Do I have a misunderstanding of what 'Is Null' is for and how it behaves? Also, in the debug log, what does
'Record(null) is null null' mean? Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the `IsNull` operator requires the condition value to be `true` or `false`, giving you two options:

1. Resource X is null (with `true`)
2. Resource X is NOT null (with `false`)

You need to update your conditions to use `$GlobalConstant.True`.

[image: Is Null is True]

The "(null) Is null null" is literally outputting that you have a null value in the comparison for the "is null", instead of having `true`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I thought 'IsNull' was implying true (anything that was null should meet the condition). I guess this explains why there is no 'IsNotNull' operator. This fixed my problems. Thanks so much!!